# Vim Omnicomplete in real time?

Tags: vim

I want my omnicomplete tooltip appear as I type, or 1 second after I stopped typing, or even after I type period.(akin to visual studio). Is that possible in Vim?

For those who have no idea what I am talking about, I want this little window to show up without pressing CTRL+X, CTRL+O or any other awkward keyboard shortcuts.

http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/dwatkins/entry/vim_omnicomplete_awesomeness/

CTRL + Space sounds like a good alternative but I am on a Macbook, my leftmost key is Fn, not Control unfortunately.

Comment: FYI, Control not on leftmost position is the preferable place. Old terminals had Ctrl just left to the space bar and it's arguably most ergonomic.

Comment: I almost always remap CapsLock to be another Ctrl

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i would recommend [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache). it looks better and works faster then AutoComplPop

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at [supertab](https://github.com/tsaleh/vim-supertab)? Not sure if that's what you're after, but maybe you'll find something interesting in the source. Good luck!

Comment: Not quiet what I was looking for but it will do.

Comment: @Rated R I guess I didn't quite follow what you meant by "real time." If you come up with something interesting (maybe even a new vim plugin!), please post here :)

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're looking for something like [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879).

This pops up the completion menu while you're typing.